# ArcGIS Tool Resample (Data Management) equivalent in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In ArcGIS tools there is one tool named Resample (Data Management), is there any equivalent tool in QGIS which performs the same task as Resample (Data Management)?

Comment: To the attention of QGIS-only users, maybe you should precise explicitely what this tool does.

Answer (score 1):

You can find one possiblity at raster-konversion-translate . There you can set the new outsize in percantages. So if you want to resample from 1x1 to 2x2 you set it to 50%.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the following **GRASS** tools from the *Processing Toolbox* which resamples raster layers to finer, coarser resolutions and the option to retain the extent of the original raster. Different methods are used depending on the tool chosen:

- [r.resample](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.resample.html): *GRASS raster map layer data resampling capability*
- [r. resample.stats](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.resamp.stats.html):  *Resamples raster map layers to a coarser grid using aggregation.*
- [r.resample.interp](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.resamp.interp.html): *Resamples raster map layers to a finer grid using interpolation.*